# How to instant search multiple indexes at the same time in Algolia ? swift

Tags: ios, swift, algolia

Is there any way to search multiple indexes at the same time in Algolia? I have been following this documentation but have been successfull in only in searching from one index at a time. 
https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-ios/getting-started.html#before-we-start

Comment: Can you please share what is your use case and what you are trying to achieve with "multi indexing"? That will help us better design this feature :)

Comment: Like there are 3-4 indexes of different types and in the same searchBar i would like to instant search every index and displaying them in tableview.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing! that will be the main use case that we will cover for sure. Stay tuned, I'll post an update as soon as we've released the support for multi-indexing

Comment: Great ! Could there also be possibly a way for differentiating the hits/ search results to know which index is this hit from . 

For example: if an user searches for 'star trek' and we have say, two indices, one called TV shows and one called Movies, we would like to show the user whether this search result falls under the TV category or the movie.

Comment: Definitely, that's noted as well, thanks for giving feedback! please feel free to give more, we love that!

Comment: You can check my updated answer, we released a first version of multi-indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Multi indexing is now available on InstantSearch iOS. You can start with the [getting started guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-ios/getting-started-part2.html#display-data-from-multiple-hits). You can also check the [2 new demos](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-ios/examples.html) that use multi-indexing: Query suggestion Demo and Movies Demo.

---

**Previous Answer**

Thank you for your interest in using InstantSearch! That's a valid question and the quick answer is that Algolia is adding support for multi indexes for InstantSearch iOS in the next month or 2 (it's our top priority).

That being said, for now, there is a way for you to do it if you use the InstantSearch Core library, by following our [Movie Search demo](https://github.com/algolia/algolia-swift-demo) and **checking out the iPad version**. If you check the [MoviesIpadViewController](https://github.com/algolia/algolia-swift-demo/blob/master/Source/MoviesIpadViewController.swift), you'll realise that we use 2 [Searcher](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-core-swift/blob/master/Sources/Searcher.swift) instances and search in both when entering a new query in the search bar.

Let us know if you have more questions!

Comment: Sure, let us know when you finish it.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)